# Cannot convert value of type 'Array<String>' to expected argument type 'String?'

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, watchconnectivity

I am using `WatchConnectivity` framework to send an array called `watchItems` of string value to the apple watch from the phone. I add the `watchItems` from the sent dictionary and add it to an array called `items` on the watch to use in a `WKInterfaceTable`.

The error is occurring for the following line when setting the text of the label to theItem.

```
for (index, theItem) in self.items.enumerate() {
    let row = self.table.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! CellRowController
    row.bookmarksCellLabel.setText(theItem)
 }
```

Heres a full explanation of what I am doing.

**iPhone**

`self.items` is an array of `NSManagedObject`s and each item has a property called `title` which is a string. So I loop through the `objects` array and add all the string values to an array called `watchItems`.

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {

    var watchItems = [""]

    for item in self.items {
       watchItems.append(item.title)
    }

    //send a reply
    replyHandler( [ "Value" : [watchItems]])

}
```

**Apple Watch**

Here I add the watchItems array from the received message dictionary to the `items` array on the watch. The `watchItems` array is an array of string values and so is the `items` array on the watch.

```
var items = [String]()

@IBAction func refreshAction() {
    let messageToSend = ["Value":"Hello iPhone"]
    session.sendMessage(messageToSend, replyHandler: { replyMessage in

         let value = replyMessage["Value"] as! String
         self.titleLabel.setText(value)

        }, errorHandler: {error in
            // catch any errors here
            print(error)
    })
}


func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {

    let value = message["Value"] as! [String]

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.items.removeAll()
        self.items.append(value)
        self.loadTableData()
    }

    //send a reply
    replyHandler(["Value":"Yes"])

}
```

Function to reload the `WKInterfaceTable` and set label as each item in the items array.

```
func loadTableData() {
    table.setNumberOfRows(self.items.count, withRowType: "CellRow")
    if self.items.count > 0 {
        for (index, theItem) in self.items.enumerate() {
            let row = self.table.rowControllerAtIndex(index) as! CellRowController
            row.cellLabel.setText(theItem)
        }
     }
}
```

I get the error when adding the string value to the `cellLabel`. Does anybody know where I may be going wrong ?

Comment: What type is self.items defined as (the items property on the watch side)?

Comment: I'm mostly an Obj-C guy but shouldn't that be `var items = [String]()`? And then use `self.items.extend(value)` instead of append

Comment: Then the error `Cannot convert value of type '[String]' to expected argument of type 'String'`  for, `self.items.append(value)` when receiving the message on the watch.

Comment: Use `extend` instead of `append` since you want to add all the items of the value array to the items array rather than add a single item

Comment: When using extend Xcode throw and error saying extend has been renamed to `appendContentsOf`. Then I get a crash with the error, `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x5d5244) to 'NSString' (0xa3b458).`

Comment: I tried creating a project myself with these code snippets, and it compiled just fine. If you are still having problems, perhaps uploading the entire project to GitHub so I can check the whole thing out?

Comment: Two questions: 1) what is `theTask`? and 2) are you aware that `items` in the WatchApp is an [array of [array of string]]? *edit*: I just saw the timestamp of the comments.. probably fixed it already, right?

Comment: @fguchelaar I have edited the question, thanks for spotting that out. I am still having the issue. All I wanted to do was send an array of string to the watch to display in the table :(

Comment: are you actually getting an exception on the row `row.cellLabel.setText(theItem)`? Then what is `CellRowController`. Did you hook up the `cellLabel` control to an `@IBOutlet`?